How to access ADB shell on Samsung Galaxy S10 stuck in boot loop?
I have a Samsung Galaxy S10 that is rooted and the bootloader is unlocked. Recently, I disabled a series of system packages, and now my phone is stuck in a boot loop. I need to re-enable those packages to fix the boot loop, but I'm unable to access the ADB shell because the device shows as "unauthorized."
Here's what I have tried so far:
adb devices
List of devices attached
R38MB0CN1MA unauthorized

Attempting to open ADB shell:
adb shell
adb: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.

I need to access the ADB shell to re-enable the packages and get my phone out of the boot loop. How can I achieve this on a Mac?
Additional Information:
Phone: Samsung Galaxy S10
Rooted: Yes
Bootloader: Unlocked
Current Mode: Stuck in boot loop

Any help or guidance on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated!

https://xdaforums.com/t/how-to-enable-access-via-adb-on-a-new-installed-os.4535165

https://xdaforums.com/t/accessing-my-phone-with-a-dead-screen.4542763/post-88016019

sorry I am lazy. will write down answer later
